# Session not set till page reload?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, reload, isset

So after a LOT of trial and error, I set up something to test whether my session is set or not, which looks like this :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo "Logged In!";
}
else {
    echo "NOT LOGGED IN!";
}
?>
```

And what I realize is that after Login ( which redirects to the site's homepage) The session is not set until I reload the entire homepagepage.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and/or knows how to get around such a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may seem obvious, but be sure that you are setting your session variable before you try to read it...Where are you setting $_SESSION['email']? You say that the act of logging in redirects the user to the homepage. Is $_SESSION['email'] already set before the redirection occurs, or is it set on the homepage itself?

Comment: Yes, When(if) the login form is validated, $_SESSION['email'] is set and then I use,for example, header('location:home.php') to redirect to the homepage @MattRabe

Comment: Ok. Are you executing session_start() on that processing page before setting $_SESSION['email'] ?

Comment: Is this piece of code the first thing on the home page?

Comment: @Rasclatt No, this is just a php file I go to to test whether the session is set. For instance, After I am redirected to www.domain.com i would enter as the url: www.domain.com/sessiontest.php

Comment: If the redirect doesn't work but reloading the same page works, then likely your session is set on your previous page (login), especially if that is the only page that can assign session variables. That would mean your problem is likely on your homepage file somewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, but I found the problem. 
Apparently I have to be extremely specific with my url in the redirect file.

I had `header('location: http://domain.com');`

instead of

`header('location: http://www.domain.com');`

...*facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

This snippet of code works for me as a test. Make sure your order of operations matches this. If that does not work, make sure you are allowing cookies in your browser. Failing that, there could be something screwy about your PHP/Apache configuration.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['test']))
{
    $_SESSION['email'] = "something ".time();
    header('location:?test');
    die;
}else{
    echo 'Value: "' .$_SESSION['email']. '"';
    echo '<br /><br /><a href="?">&lt; Do again</a>';
    die;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob at this, but I'm having a little trouble understanding your code. primarily the 3rd line, what exactly is $_GET['test'] ? what is its function here? thanks

Comment: @user3817799: `$_GET['test']` is a reference to the query string var named 'test' (e.g.: abc.com/page.php?test=123 - in this case, `$_GET['test'] == "123"`). I'm using it to allow this PHP file to perform two functions: 1) Set the `$_SESSION` var, and 2) read the `$_SESSION` var. If `$_GET['test']` is not set (which is the default) then I set the session var and redirect to ?test. When the page loads, `$_GET['test']` will be set, and the script will perform the second half. IMPORTANTLY, this also demonstrates that `session_start()` needs to occur FIRST on both of the "pages."

Answer (score 0):

Your pages need to be set up like so in this order (particularly the `session_start()`):

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// 1) Some code here to check database if username and password check out
// 2) If username and password check out and validation is good
// 3) Redirect to your next page (index.php in this case)
?>
```

index.php (home page)

```
<?php
session_start();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
EMAIL IS SET!! Great job!
<?php } else { ?>
UM...No..<?php } ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a horrible time with this.  I have an index page that loads every time and inside a content div loads specific php scripts via include.  I control the navigation of the website in this way by passing GET variables to the index.html, so my index page loads every single time no matter what content you're viewing.  The very first line of index.html was:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Some of my php scripts running as includes on the index page would set session variables then redirect to the index page and the session variable would not be there,, or they would not be set to what they should be.  It was driving me mad, I could ctrl-F5 and sometimes they would show up and sometimes not.  The only thing I can figure was that it was somehow opening different sessions for different urls that were in the address bar (by different urls I mean ones with different GET parameters.  Simply putting this at the beginning of my index.html solved all my problems.  I assume this causes the same session to open each time:

```
   <?php
   session_name('SessName');
   session_start();
```